# Issue with testing Wrapper Query Component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-testing-library

I'm very new to React testing and I'm trying to write Jest/Enzyme Unit tests for the MyReload wrapper component on top of Apollo Query that I have created. This basically adds refetchers to an array (that can be executed at later point of time).

**Usage:**

```
<MyReloadQuery id='1234 .....> // do something.. children </MyReloadQuery>
```

**Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Subscribe } from "unstated";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { MyReloadContainer } from "./MyReloadContainer";


export class MyReloadQuery extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onUnmount();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Subscribe to={[MyReloadContainer]}>
        {refetchers => (
          <Query {...this.props}>
            {(...args) => {
              const { refetch } = args[0];

              this.onUnmount = () => {
                refetchers.removeRefetcher(refetch);
              };

              refetchers.addRefetcher(refetch);

              return this.props.children(...args);
            }}
          </Query>
        )}
      </Subscribe>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm very new to React and it's testing and I'm wondering how can one test with dummy data for this one?

Can someone please enlighten me? Any help would be appreciated :pray:

Comment: to the last question, you could use the iterator of a set and exit early on find.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Thanks again for comment.

Comment: `const hasPlaystation = (store) => {
   for (const { title } of store) if (title.includes('playstation')) return true;
   return false;
  }` for example.